# How to use RichTextEditor with HTML value?

Tags: html, vaadin, richtext, vaadin-flow, delta

I am trying to use `com.vaadin.flow.component.richtexteditor.RichTextEditor` in a form and I need to get and set the **HTML** format and **not the delta format**, I further need to employ the `getValue()` and `setValue()` for homogeneity to all other fields of the form that use those methods. So I tried something like this:

```
public class HtmlEditor extends RichTextEditor {
  private HasValue<?, String> htmlValue;

  public HtmlEditor() {
    htmlValue = asHtml();
    setThemeName(RichTextEditorVariant.LUMO_COMPACT.getVariantName());
  }

  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    return StringUtils.trimToNull(htmlValue.getValue());
  }

  @Override
  public void setValue(String value) {
    htmlValue.setValue(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(value));
  }


}
```

But this does not work because RichTextEditor itself uses getValue and setValue directly expecting (I guess) delta format.

I considered wrapping RichTextEditor as a composed component, but this seems me an overkill for a simple and so usual need to read and write HTML.

Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built-in for this, no. Might be doable with some custom converter, but 'easy' would not be the correct word for that.

Edit: there is an open ticket about this, that you could comment on and upvote if the feature is important to you: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1584